# SSL/two way SSL communication issue

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, tomcat8

We have enabled SSL communication in apache Tomcat8 in the below manner,

```
<Connector port="8743" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" 
           maxThreads="500" scheme="https" secure="true" 
           connectionTimeout="300000"
           keystoreType="pkcs12"
           keystoreFile="D:\apps\certs\runtime\certs\testserver.pfx"
           keystorePass="test"
           truststoreFile="D:\apps\certs\runtime\caLists\truststore"
           truststorePass="test"
           truststoreType="jks"
           clientAuth="want" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Here testserver.pfx is our server certificate and in truststore file we have all root certificates of our inbound services.
I am able to connect other webservices without any issue but other web services not able to connect with us. Its failing due to certificate issue/SSL Handshake issue.

When I checked with them they told our application expecting client certificate from the inbound services. And they told we are using two way SSL connection but it should be single way SSL.

Can anyone please help to identify whether this configuration is single way or two way SSL communication. If it is two way communication how to change it to single way SSL commnucation.

**Update:**

I have removed test environment configuration since i want to know what is happening in production environment and provided more information about current issue.

Before this release we were using tomcat 7, Java 7 and we had their certificates(I have visited their endpoint address in IE and exported the server certificate) entries in our truststore.

In this release we are using tomcat 8(8.5.16.0), Java 8(1.8.0_152) and removed their certificate entries in our truststore. We have one ESB which is installed in different server, all the inbound requests communication will happen through this ESB.

After our changes all the inbound requests are getting failed in ESB due to SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown..this is the complete log trace.

```
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Problem writing SAAJ model to stream: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor$SAAJOutEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(SAAJOutInterceptor.java:223)[178:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-bindings-soap:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor$SAAJOutEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(SAAJOutInterceptor.java:174)[178:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-bindings-soap:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)[103:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:514)[103:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:423)[103:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.clustering.FailoverTargetSelector.performFailover(FailoverTargetSelector.java:191)[183:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-features-clustering:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.clustering.FailoverTargetSelector.complete(FailoverTargetSelector.java:150)[183:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-features-clustering:3.1.4]
    at org.esb.servicelocator.cxf.internal.LocatorTargetSelector.complete(LocatorTargetSelector.java:57)[149:locator:6.1.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.completeExchange(ClientImpl.java:536)[103:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.processResult(ClientImpl.java:584)[103:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:523)[103:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:423)[103:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.clustering.FailoverTargetSelector.performFailover(FailoverTargetSelector.java:191)[183:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-features-clustering:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.clustering.FailoverTargetSelector.complete(FailoverTargetSelector.java:150)[183:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-features-clustering:3.1.4]
    at org.esb.servicelocator.cxf.internal.LocatorTargetSelector.complete(LocatorTargetSelector.java:57)[149:locator:6.1.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.completeExchange(ClientImpl.java:536)[103:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.processResult(ClientImpl.java:584)[103:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:523)[103:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:423)[103:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfProducer.process(CxfProducer.java:153)[162:org.apache.camel.camel-cxf:2.15.4]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.SynchronousDelegateProducer.process(SynchronousDelegateProducer.java:62)[161:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.4]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)[161:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.4]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:129)[161:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.4]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[161:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.4]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)[161:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.4]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)[161:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.4]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)[161:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.4]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)[161:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.4]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.ChoiceProcessor.process(ChoiceProcessor.java:111)[161:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.4]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[161:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.4]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448)[161:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.4]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)[161:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.4]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)[161:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.4]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)[161:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.4]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)[161:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.15.4]
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfConsumer$1.asyncInvoke(CxfConsumer.java:95)[162:org.apache.camel.camel-cxf:2.15.4]
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfConsumer$1.invoke(CxfConsumer.java:75)[162:org.apache.camel.camel-cxf:2.15.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)[103:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.4]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)[:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)[:1.8.0_91]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$2.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:126)[103:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)[103:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:131)[103:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)[103:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)[103:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251)[113:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)[113:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)[113:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)[113:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:180)[113:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:293)[113:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:212)[113:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.4]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)[11:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:268)[113:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.4]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)[76:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.2.10.v20150310]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)[76:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.2.10.v20150310]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceServletHandler.doHandle(HttpServiceServletHandler.java:70)[94:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:4.2.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)[75:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.10.v20150310]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)[74:org.eclipse.jetty.security:9.2.10.v20150310]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)[75:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.10.v20150310]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)[75:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.10.v20150310]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doHandle(HttpServiceContext.java:271)[94:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:4.2.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)[76:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.2.10.v20150310]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)[75:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.10.v20150310]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)[75:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.10.v20150310]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)[75:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.10.v20150310]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerHandlerCollection.handle(JettyServerHandlerCollection.java:80)[94:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:4.2.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)[75:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.10.v20150310]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)[75:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.10.v20150310]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)[75:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.10.v20150310]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)[75:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.10.v20150310]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)[67:org.eclipse.jetty.io:9.2.10.v20150310]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)[78:org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.2.10.v20150310]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)[78:org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.2.10.v20150310]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:255)[139:woodstox-core-asl:4.4.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor$SAAJOutEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(SAAJOutInterceptor.java:215)[178:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-bindings-soap:3.1.4]
    ... 74 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)[:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)[:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023)[:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125)[:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)[:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)[:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)[:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)[:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)[:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1283)[:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1258)[:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)[:1.8.0_91]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.setupWrappedStream(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:236)[113:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1319)[113:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1279)[113:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:267)[113:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:47)[103:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.unBuffer(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:89)[103:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:63)[103:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.write(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:80)[103:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:51)[103:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.4]
    at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.flush(UTF8Writer.java:100)[139:woodstox-core-asl:4.4.1]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flush(BufferingXmlWriter.java:241)[139:woodstox-core-asl:4.4.1]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:253)[139:woodstox-core-asl:4.4.1]
    ... 75 more
```

Shall i change the clientAuth= false to avoid this issue? Will it create any other problem if i do that?

Comment: If everything works with `clientAuth="want"` in the test environment this means the client certificate authentication has no problems why do you talk so much about the SSL client certificate? Regarding Java 8 the exact version matters - please add it - the newer Java 8 versions come with unlimited strength crypto policy (allows aes256 and larger RSA key size).

Comment: @Robert i have added Java version. First configuration fails due to SSL handshake issue and the second one works. But there is no major difference between these two except the protocol. Both have same clientAuth="want", but it is working in one environment and fails in other.

Comment: Why don't you just compare both services on protocol level? Check them both using https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ and compare the enabled protocols and ciphers.

Comment: Please post the *actual error message.*. Your post is futile without tthat.

Comment: (1) you say in test they communicate "without SSL handshake" which is impossible; do you mean "without handshake _error_"? (2) "any default configuration": Most Oracle j8 updates (not sure about OpenJDK) including 8u152 default disable SSLv3 using jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms in JRE/lib/security/java.security and so do a few (free) updates of j7. But you say it works in test with config that explicitly excludes SSLv3. (3) your test config sets protocol Nio2 explicitly while the other uses HTTP/1.1 which could autoswitch to Apr, which might affect clientauth; I don't have APR to check.

Comment: 'They' are wrong. You are perfectly within your rights to request a client certificate. Depending on their configuration, they will or won't send one. The mere certificate request won't cause failure at their end, and them not sending one won't cause a failure at your end, at least until the application gets beyond the TLS handshake phase and into the authorization phase. And no client organisation should be dictating to you not to use client authentication. It's your server: you secure it how you want.

Comment: @EJP thanks for ur reply, I have updated some more information and complete log trace.

Comment: Now you're mixing things up. Your question is about *your* Tomcat Connector, which means it's about **your** server, and incoming connections with their **client** certificates. You're now saying *"I have visited **their** endpoint address in IE and exported the **server** certificate"*. So which is it? If they are calling you, then it should be about your server certificate and their client certificate. Any server certificate on their server has *nothing* to do with it.

Comment: If that's their stack trace, it shows that they sent an invalid client certificate. That's their problem. Not yours. If it's your stack trace, it shows that you, as a client, somehow sent an invalid client certificate to their server: which at least shows very poor analysis on their part.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support_-_BIO,_NIO_and_NIO2), `clientAuth` values are:

- `true` - Two-way
- `want` - Request two-way, but allow one-way
- `false` - One-way *(may require two-way for some services)*

Since you specified `want`, the server will request two-way, but the connection should still work if the client doesn't provide a client certificate.

That is the correct setting if you want some web service clients to connect without a certificate.

If the client can't handle it a request for two-way at all, you could set up a separate connector on a different port with `clientAuth="false"` (the default).

---

**UPDATE**

As for SSL protocols and ciphers in use, in Java 8 [TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 are enabled by default](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/enhancements-8.html).

If you want to see which ciphers are available and which are enabled by default, run this code:

```
SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
TreeMap<String, Boolean> ciphers = new TreeMap<>();
for (String availableCipher : ssf.getSupportedCipherSuites())
    ciphers.put(availableCipher, Boolean.FALSE);
for (String defaultCipher : ssf.getDefaultCipherSuites())
    ciphers.put(defaultCipher, Boolean.TRUE);
System.out.println("Default\tCipher");
for (Entry<String, Boolean> cipher : ciphers.entrySet())
    System.out.println((cipher.getValue() ? '*' : ' ') + "\t" + cipher.getKey());
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply, I have added some more infromation related the problem